# MongoDB query - Select one of each from non unique array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a collection with a schema of:

```
{ 
    _id: 521cc63c19752c562300001a,
    author: 'John',
    quote: 'A quote',
    type: 1,
    stars:
     [{ _id: 521cc63c19752c562300001b,
       user: 521cc63c19752c5623000003,
       date: Tue Aug 27 2013 16:31:08 GMT+0100 (IST) }]
}
```

I'm trying to select documents that have types within an specific array. For example, if the types are unique, it returns a three quotes of each type, exactly as intended:

```
db.quotes.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        "type": {
            $in: [1, 2, 3] //The unique types
        }
    }},

    // Group by the type
    {$group: {
        _id: "$type",
        id: { $first: "$_id" },
        author: { $first: "$author" },
        stars: { $first: "$stars" },
        description: { $first: "$description" }
    }},

    // Map/project the first result of each group
    // to their respective keys
    {$project: {
        _id: "$id",
        type: "$_id",
        author: "$author",
        description: "$description"
        stars: "$stars"
    }}
]);
```

My problem is that the types may not be always be unique. I could have to find three documents with the same type ([1, 1, 1]) or two the same and one unique ([1, 2, 2]). When this situation arises, it will only return one or two results due to the $group by type pipeline command. Any advice how I can supply three non-unique types and always get three quotes back of each type?

Comment: Either you should remove `$groupby` step from your query or I didn't understand you properly.

Comment: @Shad Then it returns all documents that have that type and not just one of each. I can see how I implied that, I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to need to write your own function that:

- takes your *types* array as an argument.
- Instantiates an empty *skipDocs* hash / object e.g.

  var objSkipDocs = {};
- for each element of your *types* array zeroise a key of that value in the hash.

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayTypes.length; i++) { 
         objSkipDocs[arrayTypes[i]] = 0; 
  }
- for each element of your *types* array attempt to get a document e.g.

  db.quotes.findOne({'type': arrayTypes[i] }).skip( objSkipDocs[ arrayTypes[i] ] );

  objSkipDocs[ arrayTypes[i] ] += 1;
- Do something with the retrieved document